# Java advantage of Enum

Tags: java, enums

What is the advantage of using an `Enum` class to compare something. What is the disadvantage of :

```
public static final String TRUE = "true";
public static final String FALSE = "false";

public void method1(){

    if(TRUE.equals(inputString)){
        //do some logic
    }
    else if(FALSE.equals(inputString)){
        //do some other logic
    }
}
```

Why is it recommended to use `Enum` instead of `String` in the example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One important reason is that with the `enum`, you know the value is either `TRUE` or `FALSE`; it can't be anything else. But the `String` can have any value at all, so you have to check for that. This makes code both simpler and easier to understand.

Another is that you can compare `enum` elements with `==`, but you have to use a relatively slow `equals()` call to compare `String` objects.

Comment: Thanks. Can you also tell me if there is any other use of ENUM except for == comparison?

Comment: You can also use Enums in switch statements, unlike strings (for JREs < 1.7).

Comment: Enums are objects.  They have methods.  You can add your own methods.  You can define custom implementations for specific instances of your enum.

Answer (score 2):

Resons why you should use enums:

- Enums are **strong typed**
- **Comparing enums is faster**, you can use `==` instead `equals()`
- **Enums can implement interfaces, methods and functions.** For example enum for various metric systems `Metric.EUCLID.distance(Point a, Point b));`
- There is **bunch of convenience methods out of the box** - `MyEnum[] all = MyEnum.values();` `MyEnum.valueOf("ENUM_NAME");`
- You can use them in a switch statement since Java 5, String since Java 7.
- IMO It makes code a bit more readable.